# how creating the Hala indicator with an offset(stepshift) and strategy based on this indicator and a simple strategy script in one long position

Tags: pine-script, trading

I apologize for the request to solve the trivial problem for you, but please help the newbie:
1. I want to create a moving Hull indicator with an offset - I need to implement an offset function in the indicator.
2. The crossover strategy of the “moving Hull with offset” based on a simple strategy script in a long position.
If it doesn’t make it difficult for respected experienced people, I will be very grateful for my help in the analysis.

```
1.need to embed "//shift the step
                  step_shift = input(0,"Step Shift")"
//@version=4
study(title = "Hull MA", shorttitle="HMA", overlay = true)
length = input(9, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
hullma = wma(2*wma(src, length/2)-wma(src, length), round(sqrt(length)))
plot(hullma)



2.insert the received indicator into this strategy script long position only

//@version=4
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true)
longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

12.01.2020. 
I also edited your code for a more necessary idea for checks. Now it remains to apply the correction there so that the offset works

```
 //@version=4
strategy(title = "Hull MA", shorttitle="HMA", overlay = true)

fastLength  = input(14, minval=2)
offsetfastLength  = input(0)
src1   = input(close, title="Source")
slowLength  = input(28, minval=2)
offsetslowLength   = input(0)
src2   = input(open, title="Source")


fastHma = wma(2*wma(src1, fastLength/2)-wma(src1, fastLength), round(sqrt(fastLength)))
slowHma = wma(2*wma(src2, slowLength/2)-wma(src2, slowLength), round(sqrt(slowLength)))
longCondition   = crossover(fastHma, slowHma)
closeCondition  = crossunder(fastHma, slowHma)

strategy.entry("long",strategy.long,when = longCondition)
strategy.close("long",when = closeCondition)

plot(fastHma, "fastHma", color.orange, offset = offsetfastLength)
plot(slowHma, "slowHma", color.blue, offset = offsetslowLength)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
strategy(title = "Hull MA", shorttitle="HMA", overlay = true)

fastLength  = input(14, minval=2)
slowLength  = input(28, minval=2)
offsetHMA   = input(0, "Offset in the future", minval=0)
src         = input(close, title="Source")

fastHma = wma(2*wma(src, fastLength/2)-wma(src, fastLength), round(sqrt(fastLength)))[offsetHMA]
slowHma = wma(2*wma(src, slowLength/2)-wma(src, slowLength), round(sqrt(slowLength)))[offsetHMA]
longCondition   = crossover(fastHma, slowHma)
shortCondition  = crossunder(fastHma, slowHma)

if longCondition
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
if shortCondition
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)

plot(fastHma, "fastHma", color.orange)
plot(slowHma, "slowHma", color.blue)
plotchar(longCondition, "longCondition", "▲", location.belowbar, color.green)
plotchar(shortCondition, "shortCondition", "▼", location.abovebar, color.maroon)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much human! Now I will apply and study for me it is very important, thanks for the help!) many thanks, you Genius

Comment: there is a problem .... the strategy does not see and does not take into account the "offset" parameter ...

Comment: Updated code so it does, but only allowed offset to the right, so making the signals late.

Comment: tell me why it was not possible to make a negative offset, but only to the right? it's impossible?

Comment: Because now the offset is on the Hma calcs so that the same offset shows on plots. And calcs can't use future data because it isn't there yet, so offset can't be into the future. You could always add an independent offset to be used on the plots which could plot in the future, like in my first example.